# parts of speech of a word in a sentence

Tags: descriptive-grammar

What is the part of speech of *before* in the following:

- Long before anyone coined the term sci-fi?

I am wondering whether it is an adjective, an adverb, or a preposition?

Comment: I take it as a preposition, with a clausal complement. The adverb "long" is a complement of "before".

Comment: *Long before anyone coined the term sci-fi* is not a "sentence".  It's an ***adverbial** phrase* - syntactically equivalent to, for example, ***long ago***, or ***recently***.

Comment: Some would say that adverbial clauses are introduced by subordinating conjunctions, but there's effectively no difference between them and prepositions, as @BillJ suggests. _Before noon_ and _before he arrives_ do the same job, after all.